# Unbreakablecoin - Block Height Stopped Moving

Tags: blockchain, protocol, synchronization, consensus

I am running a full Unbreakablecoin (a Bitcoin clone) node.

Blocks were being generated every few minutes or so, until about a week ago. Now, the block height has been stuck at 82666 for multiple days. Also and all peers seem to have one thing in common: They have some reference to a single IP address of `71.71.215.6`

Is this some sort of hack/attack? If yes, how is it being accomplished?

`~ unbreakablecoin-cli getpeerinfo`

```
[
    {
        "id" : 111,
        "addr" : "198.27.81.114:54022",
        "addrlocal" : "71.71.215.6:9336",
        "services" : "0000000000000001",
        "lastsend" : 1515125911,
        "lastrecv" : 1515125911,
        "bytessent" : 51777,
        "bytesrecv" : 52217,
        "conntime" : 1515032269,
        "pingtime" : 0.11530600,
        "version" : 70002,
        "subver" : "/Satoshi:0.10.3/",
        "inbound" : true,
        "startingheight" : 82666,
        "banscore" : 0,
        "synced_headers" : 82666,
        "synced_blocks" : 82666,
        "inflight" : [
        ],
        "whitelisted" : false
    },
    {
        "id" : 116,
        "addr" : "173.208.145.82:55264",
        "addrlocal" : "71.71.215.6:9336",
        "services" : "0000000000000001",
        "lastsend" : 1515125940,
        "lastrecv" : 1515125940,
        "bytessent" : 50453,
        "bytesrecv" : 51159,
        "conntime" : 1515033251,
        "pingtime" : 0.14900100,
        "version" : 70002,
        "subver" : "/Satoshi:0.10.3/",
        "inbound" : true,
        "startingheight" : 82666,
        "banscore" : 0,
        "synced_headers" : -1,
        "synced_blocks" : -1,
        "inflight" : [
        ],
        "whitelisted" : false
    },
    ...
    ALL PEERS HAVE "addrlocal" : "71.71.215.6:9336"
    ...
]
```

`~ unbreakablecoin-cli getblockchaininfo`

```
{
    "chain" : "main",
    "blocks" : 82666,
    "headers" : 82666,
    "bestblockhash" : "00000000000000010aacfc4d82170ae9e57854852f30f62d63393a64cab8d4b8",
    "difficulty" : 2079545789.81736517,
    "verificationprogress" : 0.89795278,
    "chainwork" : "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a36f3a84fc39816ff7"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also and all peers seem to have one thing in common: They have some reference to a single IP address of `71.71.215.6`

That's unrelated. That should be your IP address.

Either you have become disconnected from the network or all miners have left the network.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed the obvious fact that `71.71.215.6` is **my** IP. Thanks for that.

It is possible that other miners have left, I picked this coin specifically to try and solo mine a block (for interest, not profit).